Can Index of Coincidence be used for ciphertext containing letters, numbers, and symbols? (All characters in cipher are from ASCII table)
I have been trying to figure out how to approach performing cryptanalysis on the following ciphertext, but am stumped on whether I can use classical techniques such as IoC to derive useful information about the cryptosystem used and move towards breaking it.
Ciphertext: +9-7!!/@ 2enr?hqj+r,r+c?)j?96exd.?i 7kj\psq3euj@x.yt5 ,33szl'!(
My question is whether it is a valid idea to used Index of Coincidence to evaluate the above ciphertext, and if so, how do I adjust the formula to accommodate an ASCII alphabet?

Are you sure this is ASCII? Because often when I see this kind of ciphertext it is binary which is printed as ASCII, and that would destroy all control characters and possibly characters out of range. I'm also left wandering if this is the full ASCII, many symbols and all caps are missing. Sometimes that means the actual text is simply an encoding scheme such as base 64 where the characters have been substituted. It is of course possible to use IoC but the sample size is very small, even smaller than the alphabet. So IoC will probably not result in a very meaningful value.
